# Thymeleaf Shiro dialect custom expression

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf, shiro

I am iterating through a list and setting a `shiro:hasPermission` attribute to each `div` like this

```html
<div th:each="element : ${elements}" shiro:hasPermission="${element.permission}">
    <span th:text="${element.name}"></span>
</div>
```

where `${element.permission}` is a permission string.

The div is not rendering even when the user has the permission. I have tried using `th:attr` like this:

```html
<div th:each="element : ${elements}" th:attr="shiro:hasPermission=${element.permission}">
    <span th:text="${element.name}"></span>
</div>
```

Still not working. I think the usage of `shiro:hasPermission="${element.permission}"` is not correct. How do I fix this?

I am using Spring MVC + Thymeleaf + [Thymeleaf Shiro dialect](https://github.com/theborakompanioni/thymeleaf-extras-shiro).

Comment: first check if permissions are displayed correctly, eg. sysout them or display them in the browser using th:text="${element.permision}. It is possible that they are not formatted in a way for shiro to understand: maybe you need to format it: shiro:hasPermission="'user:'+${element.permission}" so it can look like "user:create"

Comment: @Blejzer I have checked the expression using th:text="${element.permission}". That works fine. I need to know whether shiro:hasPermission can evaluate the expression ${element.permission}  correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the author of the [thymeleaf-extras-shiro](https://github.com/theborakompanioni/thymeleaf-extras-shiro) library.

Version 1.2.2-SNAPSHOT supports expressions.

Comment: @tbk I am using thymeleaf-extras-shiro version 1.0.0. Is there any solution, without upgrading to version 1.2.2 ?

Comment: @faizi I am afraid that is not possible. Try upgrading to 1.2.2 - there are no breaking changes.